# Minkowski sums of Convex Hulls

Tags: convex-hulls

How do I prove that the Convexhull(p1) +(Minskowski Sum) Convexhull(p2) = Convexhull(p1+p2), Where p1 and p2 are convex polygons.

Answer (score 0):

Since $p_1$ and $p_2$ are convex, you have $\text{CH}(p_1)=p_1$ and $\text{CH}(p_2)=p_2$.

Since $p_1$ and $p_2$ are convex, $p_1+p_2$ is also convex so $\text{CH}(p_1+p_2)=p_1+p_2$.

Comment: I think it's worth showing that the Minkowsi sum of convex sets is convex, since that is the key to this proof.

Comment: Is the minkowski sum of p1 & p2 the same as the convexhull of p1 & p2 ?